# if this then that style rules on a class

Tags: c#

What i'm trying to do is have a set of rules against property's so say i have class:

```
 public class OrderHeader
    {           
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public string PlainLabel { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryCode { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Address3 { get; set; }
        public string Address4 { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }    
    }
```

I want to create some kind of rules for the classes and store this in some kind of SQL database or XML file for example:

If the Customer = "ZZZ999" and the postcode = "PO4 9BQ" and PlainLabel = 1 then change the DeliveryCode = "NextDay"

If the Customer = "ABC123" change the DeliveryCode = "PalletNextDay"

I could write the code in every time as a if statement in a class but i'm looking for something more dynamic something that can be done outside of the source code. I cant think of a way i can achieve this.

Comment: If the 'DeliveryCode' is the dynamic field that you want to calculate, implement your logic inside the getter method of the DeliveryCode property. Yes, you can have some set of rules in xml, and probably the xml can be loaded when you instantiate the class or you can have it in a separate class and that can be shared across.

Comment: You can save your rule sets as, say, XML nodes with one Result child and a number of Condition children. There's not really a single way to do this, though, so this question might end up closed for being too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your rules in a data file. For example, in XML format, it could look something like this:

```
<Ruleset>
    <Rule>
        <Condition Property="Customer" Value="ZZZ999" />
        <Condition Property="PostCode" Value="PO4 9BQ" />
        <Condition Property="PlainLabel" Value="1" />
        <Set Property="DeliveryCode" Value="NextDay" />
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
        <Condition Property="Customer" Value="ABC123" />
        <Set Property="DeliveryCode" Value="PalletNextDay" />
    </Rule>
</Ruleset>
```

Then you could have some class `RuleManager` that reads the data into a list of `Rule` objects, then checks/applies the rules to a given `OrderHeader` class, using either a look-up table or Reflection to get/set the data dynamically.

You know, just as an example.